# Without Match, how do I remove songs from the cloud?

Tags: itunes

My daughter downloaded a lot of pop music through my iTunes account which re downloads to my iPad and iPhone every time I sync them. How do I delete this music from the cloud. I do not use Match

Comment: Are talking about purchased songs ?

Comment: Yes. She purchased them using my account

Comment: I expressed this inaccurately. The song titles download to my music lists and she purchased such a lot that it makes it difficult to browse

Comment: I don't believe there is such an option. However, you can stop them from downloading to your iOS devices by going to System Settings -> iTunes & App Store and turning "iTunes" off under the section "Automatic Downloads"

Answer (score 1):

You can have her delete it / stop it being stored in the cloud (see this help page: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201323 ) - basically just click 'Also delete this song from iCloud'.

Alternatively keep them in iCloud but just turn off Automatic Downloads as suggested above by GeF.

EDIT: Remember, choosing to 'Also delete this song from iCloud' doesn't mean the purchase is wasted - you can always re-download previously purchased tracks.